# Angular Help: drop-down with select all selected by default

Tags: angular, select, checkbox, angular-material, dropdown

It looks like by default the dropdown loads the list but keeps the boxes unchecked. But I want to have the boxes checked by default, since they are actually loaded. Is this possible? I am using Angular Material.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option (click)="selectAll(ev)" #ev>
        Select all
    </mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList"
        [value]="topping">
            {{topping}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: all you need to set your toppings list value to default value instead of null or empty, if the toppings value be there in form it will be shown selected by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can achieve this by setting you toppings formControl value from you component.

See below code:

```
  this.toppings.setValue(this.toppingList);
```

Comment: @Miguel Bastos hope this works for you. please let me know if anything required.

Answer (score -1):

Include your **select all** option also in an array that you loop for listing options. Then add the items that need to be selected to an array

selected: string[] = ['Select all'];

Here you need only the 'Select all' option. So add that item only in the list

<mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple **[(ngModel)]="selected"**>

toppings = new FormControl();
toppingList: string[] = ['Select all','Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
selected: string[] = ['Select all']

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple [(ngModel)]="selected">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[CheckThisExample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-with-checkbox)